# Processing Large Data Sets in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, doparallel, parallel-foreach

I have a data set of ~5mm rows of businesses with contact information (ID(int), Email(text), BusinessPhone(text), WorkPhone(text), CellPhone(text)) - over 3 million of these rows contain duplicate data. But the dupes aren't exact dupes - for example, there may be phone numbers that are in multiple rows with different email addresses.

I want to get each row to have unique information so that I have no duplicate phone numbers or emails in my data file. I plan to do this by aggregating the columns into lists by a new column. This column (we'll call ROWIDs) should be a concatenation of all the IDs that contain 1 or more of the contact data points (Email, BusinessPhone, WorkPhone, CellPhone) that appear in that row.

I have written code that works for small sample sizes but I cannot figure out how to scale it.

Note: rows with missing phone number (any of the 3 cols) have an 'NA' text placeholder.
Row example:

```
before:
ID         Email BusinessPhone   WorkPhone    CellPhone
1  test@mail.com    5555555555          NA   9998887777
2             NA    5555555555   873998898           NA

Desired After:
ID         Email BusinessPhone   WorkPhone    CellPhone ROWIDs
1  test@mail.com    5555555555          NA   9998887777    1,2
2             NA    5555555555   873998898           NA    1,2
```

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())
getDoParWorkers() # (4)

#################### GET MATCHING ROW IDs ######################################################
d = ID(int), Email(char), BusinessPhone(char), WorkPhone(char), CellPhone(char), ROWIDs(all values are '0', col is character vector)

row = function(d) {

foreach(i = 1:nrow(d),.packages = c('dplyr','data.table','tidyverse')) %dopar% {

# 1. IDENTIFY LIST OF ROW IDS THAT CONTAIN CONTACT DATA FROM THE GIVEN ROW:
rowIDList = d[(emailp == emailp[i] & emailp != '') | 
              (BusinessPhone %in% c(BusinessPhone[i],WorkPhone[i],CellPhone[i]) & BusinessPhone != 0) | 
              (WorkPhone %in% c(BusinessPhone[i],WorkPhone[i],CellPhone[i]) & WorkPhone != 0) |
              (CellPhone %in% c(BusinessPhone[i],WorkPhone[i],CellPhone[i]) & CellPhone != 0),
            paste(ID, sep = ',')] %>% as.integer()

# 2. GET THE ROW IDS INTO CHARACTER FORM TO LIST THEM IN THE NEW COLUMN:
rowIDs = paste(rowIDList, collapse = ',') %>% as.character()

# 3. EDIT THE NEW COLUMN FOR THE SUBSET OF ROWS THAT CONTAIN DATA FROM THE ROW IN THE LOOP ITERATION: 
d[ID %in% rowIDList,
  try := rep(rowIDs,
             length(rowIDList))]


}
}
```

For a random sample of 1000 rows, system.time follows:
User: 0.75
system: 0.12
Elapsed: 1.35

This increases exponentially at 5,000 rows:
user: 12.55
system: 1.50
elapsed: 16.72

And 10,000:
user: 50.97
system: 16.77
elapsed: 71.88

This came a long way from where I started but this is as far as I can take it with my current skills. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you separate your data into multiple tables? One with the invariant data (e.g. ID, birthdate), one for the mails (ID, mail), one for the business phone (ID, phone number), etc. As a relational data set identifying individuals with ID and getting there info from other tables

Comment: Even if I did that, I would still have to merge the duplicate rows and assign a single rowID to each row.

Comment: The idea would be to find a unique identifier per individual and use it to link all the tables together. This way each table contains unique values but you don't lose anything and limit duplication because two different mail will not imply repeating all the other fields. In the end what will you do with these data? This will inform a lot how you need to format them

Comment: @Gallarus, I appreciate the input re: database best practices, but I have a messy file that I need to de-dupe before making that decision.

Comment: ok, I think I am missunderstanding your question. Can you provide and example of input data and result you would want? Something like 10 lines of messy data and what you should have in the end.

Comment: Hi @Gallarus - I just added the desired output in the question.

Comment: Ok I see. Is your final goal to have this new column or in the end do you want the minimal amount of lines? For your example it would mean keeping only one line with no NAs at all using the info from the two original ones. Multiple lines would be kept only when there are for example different mails for a given phone number

Comment: @Gallarus I just want to add the column for now. Then, I'll aggregate the columns by the new field and put the other columns in lists and figure out what to do with them (might take the first value, might take several values and do a text-to-columns kind of thing to create new cols, etc.) but no matter what I'm going to do, I need to identify which of the rows go together.

Comment: In the end I don't know how to achieve what you want given the size of your data set. I think you dont but I prefer asking directly, you don't have any field that has no missing data?

Comment: can you share some stats abt your actual dataset? e.g. `d[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN)]`

Comment: @PaulWeissburg if you are ready to use python, there is [this example](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/data_deduplication.html) that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is fast enough for your dataset, you can use `igraph` to identify your clusters of id that refer to the same person:

```
library(igraph)
edges <- melt(DT[, (names(DT)) := lapply(.SD, as.character)], id.vars="ID", na.rm=TRUE)[, 
    if (.N > 1L) transpose(combn(ID, 2L, simplify=FALSE)), value][, (1) := NULL]
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, FALSE)
mem <- setDT(stack(clusters(g)$membership))[, ROWIDs := toString(ind), values]
DT[mem, on=.(ID=ind), ROWIDs := ROWIDs]
DT
```

output:

```
   ID         Email BusinessPhone WorkPhone CellPhone ROWIDs
1:  1 test@mail.com             5      <NA>         7   1, 2
2:  2          <NA>             5         6      <NA>   1, 2
3:  3 aaaa@mail.com          <NA>      <NA>      <NA>   3, 4
4:  4 aaaa@mail.com          <NA>         1      <NA>   3, 4
5:  5 bbbb@mail.com          <NA>         3      <NA>   5, 6
6:  6          <NA>          <NA>         3      <NA>   5, 6
7:  7 cccc@mail.com          <NA>      <NA>         4   7, 8
8:  8          <NA>          <NA>      <NA>         4   7, 8
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("
ID         Email BusinessPhone   WorkPhone    CellPhone
1  test@mail.com             5          NA            7
2             NA             5           6           NA
3  aaaa@mail.com            NA          NA           NA
4  aaaa@mail.com            NA           1           NA
5  bbbb@mail.com            NA           3           NA
6             NA            NA           3           NA
7  cccc@mail.com            NA          NA            4
8             NA            NA          NA            4
")
```